# Sonarqube,using Jquery library for creating custom web pages

Tags: jquery, sonarqube

I have created a plugin for Sonarqube 6.4 with a custom web page containing mixed Javascript and Jquery code. Now when I tried to run the plugin in Sonarqube 7.2, the web part is not working; showing an error at the Jquery reference("ReferenceError: $ is not defined").

Does that mean I can't use Jquery for the web part for version 7.2?  I read from the API documentation that SonarQube doesn't guarantee any Javascript libraries available at runtime. If we need some, have to include them in the final file.

How to include the jquery library so that I can keep my code unchanged?  I have tried ways like adding jquery in the src/main/resources/static directory and loading the jquery from Javascript but it didn't work.

Comment: Show us the code you use when loading jquery. Is using a [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) a possile option?

Comment: CDN is not an option for us.  I have started by putting a small image to the src/main/resources/static directory. (my page is  src/main/resources/my_page.js) . To get the image in my_page.js, I tried the following code.   

  `var x = document.createElement("IMG");
  x.setAttribute("src", "../../static/download.gif");
  options.el.appendChild(x);`  

   but its not working.